# WPF How do I set datatrigger for group of radiobuttons?

Tags: wpf, radio-button, datatrigger

I have stack panel with two groups (defined by group name) of radiobuttons. How can I set data trigger just for one group of them?

So far I tried following code which is not working

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="GroupName" Value="MaterialGroup"></Condition>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding BooleanProperty}" Value="true"></Condition>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters x:Uid="btn2">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="true"></Setter>
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>




<RadioButton GroupName="MaterialGroup" Style="{StaticResource AsToggleButton}" Content="{Binding ActualMaterialName}" Margin="0,0,5,0"></RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="MaterialGroup" x:Uid="btn2" Style="{StaticResource AsToggleButton}" Content="{Binding NextMaterialName}" Margin="0,0,5,0"></RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="MaterialGroup" Style="{StaticResource AsToggleButton}" Content="Text" Margin="0,0,5,0" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Unchecked="RadioButton_Unchecked"></RadioButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your implicit style won't get applied when you set the `Style` property of the `RadioButton` elements to `{StaticResource AsToggleButton}`.

Second, all three `RadioButton` elements in your sample markup belongs to the same group.

Third, only *one* `RadioButton` in a single group can actually be selected. That's the purpose of using a `GroupName` in the first place.

As to your actual issue, you could set the `IsChecked` property of a `RadioButton` in the "MaterialGroup" only by using a Multi**Data**Trigger with conditions.

This works, i.e. only one of the radio buttons in the "MaterialGroup" will be selected when `BooleanProperty` source property returns true:

```
<Style x:Key="theStyle"  TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding GroupName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="MaterialGroup"></Condition>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding BooleanProperty}" Value="true"></Condition>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="true"></Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

```
<RadioButton GroupName="MaterialGroup" Content="ActualMaterialName" Style="{StaticResource theStyle}" />
<RadioButton GroupName="MaterialGroup" Content="Binding NextMaterialName" Style="{StaticResource theStyle}" />
<RadioButton GroupName="SomeOtherGroup" Content="Text" Style="{StaticResource theStyle}" />
```

The third `RadioButton` that belongs to "SomeOtherGroup" won't be affected.

Comment: Thats excatly I wanted to achieve. Just one more thing: how can I set IsChecked just one of the buttonts of "MaterialGroup" defined for example by a name?

Comment: You could for example set the Tag property of one of them and then add another Condition that binds to the Tag property of the RadioButton similar to the Condition that binds to the GroupName property.